# resize script nor executing for multiple images

Tags: php, class, image-resizing

i am getting this error when i attempt to use the image resize script for each of the multiple images

the error:`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SimpleImage`

i am using the resize script by ***whitehat***

my script for handling multiple file uploads

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
{   
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];//temp file
$image_name = $key.$_FILES['image']['name'][$key];//ini file name

////resize image------
include('resizer.php'); 
$image = new SimpleImage(); 
$image->load($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key]); 
$image->resize(150,150);
$image->save('photos/'.$image_name.''); 
////----end resizer---- 

move_uploaded_file($file,"photos/".$image_name);
}
```

**what should i do to fix my problem**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `include` inside of a loop, all of the included script gets run repeatedly. Place `include("resizer.php")` before the `foreach`